# Nifi secure connection no ciphers

Tags: ssl, hadoop2, apache-nifi, bigdata

I'm using nifi and I started to configure it for https in order to enable users. Nifi does not work, jetty Web server fails saying there are not ciphers.  No idea how to debug this, any hint? 
The same certificates have been tested on my computers and they work.
Any help appreciated

**Update**

Well... I enabled the SSL logging. 
The biggest difference is about the Java environment, on the production server is `java-1.8.0-openjdk`, on my local machine is `java-8-oracle`.
There are still some important differences between the logs.

As ssl negotiation reference see this [POST](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/25073/public-key-in-ssl-protocol) about how the protocol is supposed to work and the sessions involved.

The most dramatic differences are

no `*** ECDH ServerKeyExchange` session on production host.

Log starting from ClientHello is much different between the two machines:

Local ( I truncated too long lines and reported only little log session )

```
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 2028150611 bytes = { 31, 20, 137, 167, 52, 224, 12, 129, 113, 59, 113, 45, 161, 54, 164, 147, 115, 148

Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_2
cc:0xa8, Unknown 0xcc:0x14, Unknown 0xcc:0x13, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, T
TH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, SSL_RS

Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
Unsupported extension type_23, data: 
Unsupported extension type_35, data: 
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withRSA, SHA512withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA2

Unsupported extension status_request, data: 01:00:00:00:00
Unsupported extension type_18, data: 
Unsupported extension type_16, data: 00:0c:02:68:32:08:68:74:74:70:2f:31:2e:31
Unsupported extension type_30032, data: 
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {unknown curve 29, secp256r1, secp384r1}
***
%% Initialized:  [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
%% Initialized:  [Session-2, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
matching alias: 1
matching alias: 1
matching alias: 1
matching alias: 1
%% Negotiating:  [Session-1, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256]
%% Negotiating:  [Session-2, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256]
*** ServerHello, TLSv1.2
*** ServerHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  RandomCookie:  GMT: 1459404759 bytes = { GMT: 1459404759 bytes = { 196, 84, 148, 21, 202, 175, 156, 35, 50,
2 }
Session ID:  {87, 253, 192, 215, 210, 220, 163, 93, 88, 20, 237, 50, 37, 61, 50, 192, 225, 180, 252, 8, 19, 154, 0, 18, 13

Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Compression Method: 0
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
***
Cipher suite:  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
*** Certificate chain
47, 15, 107, 214, 199, 60, 245, 207, 215, 148, 102, 224, 0, 41, 172, 70, 101, 85, 85, 173, 79, 238, 15, 167, 136, 20, 14, 
Session ID:  {87, 253, 192, 215, 117, 67, 238, 169, 141, 93, 171, 129, 181, 146, 239, 178, 242, 31, 104, 115, 209, 119, 20

Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Compression Method: 0
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
***
Cipher suite:  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=*.buongiorno.com, OU=PTY-SYS, O=BUONGIORNO SPA, L=Parma, ST=Parma, C=IT

***
*** ECDH ServerKeyExchange
Signature Algorithm SHA512withRSA
Server key: Sun EC public key, 256 bits
  public x coord: 75079925706380992652797512247021193282035431148032843217618352685456618206389
  public y coord: 43896241059818662260698096293954076915685388487376127769285950062051599700758
  parameters: secp256r1 [NIST P-256, X9.62 prime256v1] (1.2.840.10045.3.1.7)
*** CertificateRequest
Cert Types: RSA, DSS, ECDSA
Supported Signature Algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA,

Cert Authorities:
<CN=thawte SSL CA - G2, O="thawte, Inc.", C=US>
*** ServerHelloDone
NiFi Web Server-21, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 1753
NiFi Web Server-21, called closeInbound()
NiFi Web Server-21, fatal error: 80: Inbound closed before receiving peer's close_notify: possible truncation attack?
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Inbound closed before receiving peer's close_notify: possible truncation attack?
%% Invalidated:  [Session-2, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256]
NiFi Web Server-21, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = internal_error
NiFi Web Server-21, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
*** ECDH ServerKeyExchange
Signature Algorithm SHA512withRSA
Server key: Sun EC public key, 256 bits
  public x coord: 115351230770955196648507742599468345245507684591583302635044967727219906604428
  public y coord: 93087459299146270258246635135187638789539141095594448725666354447366218509864
  parameters: secp256r1 [NIST P-256, X9.62 prime256v1] (1.2.840.10045.3.1.7)
*** CertificateRequest
Cert Types: RSA, DSS, ECDSA
Supported Signature Algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA,

....
```

On production things are differents:

( I truncated too long lines and reported only little log session  )

```
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: -1695295875 bytes = { 197, 207, 66, 60, 4, 242, 21, 101, 190, 160, 124, 185, 72, 238, 141, 237, 251

Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_12
ES_256_GCM_SHA384, Unknown 0xcc:0xa9, Unknown 0xcc:0xa8, Unknown 0xcc:0x14, Unknown 0xcc:0x13, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES
CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TL
H_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
Extension server_name, server_name: [type=host_name (0), value=nifi-dev.buongiorno.com]
Unsupported extension type_23, data: 
Unsupported extension type_35, data: 
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withRSA, SHA512withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, S

Unsupported extension status_request, data: 01:00:00:00:00
Unsupported extension type_18, data: 
Unsupported extension type_16, data: 00:0c:02:68:32:08:68:74:74:70:2f:31:2e:31
Unsupported extension type_30032, data: 
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {unknown curve 29, java.security.spec.ECParameterSpec@7862cc21, java.security.s

***
%% Initialized:  [Session-4, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
matching alias: 1
%% Negotiating:  [Session-4, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384]
*** ServerHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1459415539 bytes = { 67, 58, 139, 150, 47, 53, 247, 222, 255, 192, 141, 66, 114, 19, 171, 52, 6, 18

Session ID:  {87, 253, 234, 243, 97, 92, 182, 14, 121, 224, 54, 149, 111, 196, 87, 79, 36, 149, 33, 51, 182, 47, 184, 6

Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Compression Method: 0
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
Extension server_name, server_name: 
***
Cipher suite:  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
*** Certificate chain

chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=*.buongiorno.com, OU=PTY-SYS, O=BUONGIORNO SPA, L=Parma, ST=Parma, C=IT
  Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  :
  . 

*** CertificateRequest
Cert Types: RSA, DSS, ECDSA
Supported Signature Algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDS
withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA
Cert Authorities:
<CN=thawte SSL CA - G2, O="thawte, Inc.", C=US>
*** ServerHelloDone
NiFi Web Server-16, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 1428
NiFi Web Server-21, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 7
*** Certificate chain
<Empty>
***
```

**UPDATE 2**

I asked to install Java 8 and now keyexchange works, at this point my problems are going go vanish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can provide the output (sanitized, if necessary) of your `$NIFI_HOME/logs/nifi-app.log` and `$NIFI_HOME/logs/nifi-bootstrap.log`, as well as the hardware, OS, JRE, and NiFi version you are using, that will help diagnose. Here are a couple common causes:

- The certificate in the keystore is invalid (expired, not yet valid, can't validate the chain) and thus the available cipher suites that depend on an RSA/DSA key for signature or encryption are skipped by Jetty. You can check this by adding a new argument in `$NIFI_HOME/conf/bootstrap.conf`: `java.arg.15=-Djavax.net.debug=ssl,handshake` (where the argument number is updated to ensure it does not conflict with an existing argument). This will add substantial output to your log file covering the truststore configuration and every TLS handshake negotiation, including which cipher suites Jetty sees as available.

  - There was a minor issue where dynamically-generated certificates loaded into a keystore could not be used to provide `TLSv1.1` cipher suites in test cases. See [NIFI-1688 PR 624](https://github.com/apache/nifi/pull/624/commits/4b3955155a0cd8631594cc38065266f7a66d8058)
- The JRE running NiFi does not make any cipher suites available that the browser will accept. This is less common, but JRE 7 makes `TLSv1.0` the default, and some browsers (nightly builds, etc.) may restrict TLS to `TLSv1.1` or `TLSv1.2` only. You can verify this by running the following command: `$ openssl s_client -connect <host:port> -debug -state -cert <path_to_your_cert.pem> -key <path_to_your_key.pem> -CAfile <path_to_your_CA_cert.pem>`. NiFi `0.x` can run on Java 7, but NiFi `1.x` requires Java 8+. If you are restricted to Java 7, you can explicitly enable these protocols via another Java argument: `java.arg.16=-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Andy, tomorrow I'll try to change bootstrap.conf in order to log ssl. Understand what is going on will be very useful.